# "in vfork() , after calling _exit() the child never comes back to the execution " is this true?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, fork

I am working on the unix system calls and process control.
I know that when vfork() is called , the control given to the child process and when child process is done , it calls _exit() , and then the control goes to parent .

Question no 1. is :  " I want to bring the child process to the execution , just after the parent process " ,,, is it possible ?

if no : how parent and child can run concurrently in case of vfork() ???
if yes : why we need to use the vfork() (most of the functionality is same as fork())

Question no 2. is I know the process structure of both fork and vfork , but unable to catch where to use which?

please assist.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer to question 2 is: Always use `fork`. Never use `vfork`.

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking in question 1. A `vfork`ed process can only use two system calls: `_exit` and `execve`. (Actually, it can use any of the `exec` family, but `execve` is the most common.) Once it does one of those things it is either dead (`_exit`) or no longer a `vfork` (`exec*`), and the parent will no longer be blocked. So once the child has a new memory image, the child and the parent can coexist.

In the normal case, the child will attempt to call `execve`, which will never return unless it fails, and then immediately call `_exit`, which will only happen if the `execve` fails.

The child cannot call `dup` or `close`, which are often required in order to properly set up a child process. It cannot modify any memory (because the memory belongs to the parent.) So it's very rarely even useful.

Once upon a time, process creation was slow. These days, it's much faster, and most unix-like OS's (including Linux and FreeBSD) use "copy-on-write", which considerably reduces the cost of a forked child which doesn't modify memory (or modifies very little memory). So the restrictions imposed and lack of safety provided by `vfork` are no longer useful.

`vfork` was removed from Posix in the 2008 edition, and should be considered deprecated.

If you really find that `fork` is a performance issue, you should consider using `posix_spawn`, if it is available on your system. (As far as I know, it is available on recent versions of Linux, and has been available for quite a while on FreeBSD and Solaris.) That may actually call `vfork`, but it will at least handle the details without resulting in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> Question no 1. is : " I want to bring the child process to the execution , just after the parent process "

Pretty clearly that is not what `vfork()` is for.  However, that is sort of what the exec group of system calls (`execl`, `execv`, etc.) do, except the child process must be a stand-alone executable.  If you just want one thing to happen after another thing, you don't need to fork or exec anything, just put the code in the correct order ;)

> Question no 2. is I know the process structure of both fork and vfork , but unable to catch where to use which?

`vfork()` is more specialized and restricted, so in general you would use `fork()`.  The linux vfork man page gives a clue about its use value:

> vfork()  is  a  special case of clone(2).  It is used to create new
>   processes without copying the page tables of the parent process.  **It
>   may be useful in performance-sensitive applications where a child is
>   created which then immediately issues an execve(2).**